# How can I do this type conversion?

Tags: c++

My code is here.

```
struct process *init_process (char *programName, int startTime, int cpuTime) {
    struct process *proc;
    proc = (malloc(sizeof(struct process)));
    if (proc == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal error: memory allocation failure.\nTerminating.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    proc->programName = programName;
    proc->cpuTime = cpuTime;
    proc->startTime = startTime;
    proc->next = NULL;
    return(proc);
};
```

The compiler says that "error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘process*’" in line 3.
I try to use process*(malloc(sizeof(struct process))) to do the type conversion but the compiler says that 'error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token' this time.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: try proc = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));

Comment: you should not need to cast the return from `malloc()`. Could you post the definition of the struct pls?

Comment: You are using a C++ compiler. Either write C++ code or switch to a C compiler.

Comment: @n.m: How did you know he was using c++?

Comment: because in c++ there is no implicit cast for void*, wich exists in c.

Comment: @Jimbo: Implicit conversion from `void*` to other pointer types is valid in C but not valid in C++. OTOH a `;` after a function definition is not valid C but valid C++.

Comment: I would consider using calloc() rather than malloc().  Also consider renaming process_init() to process_new() or process_alloc() to clarify that it allocates memory.

Comment: You could write: `struct process *proc = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));` or `struct process *proc = (struct process *)malloc(sizeof(*proc));` which would pass the compiler. When you try writing `proc = process * malloc(...)`, the compiler assumes you're multiplying, which isn't allowed with pointers. In C++, but not C, you can use `type(value)` casts but only for single-word type names (so `process *` cannot be used with that cast notation). But your best solution is to compile C with C compiler, not a C++ compiler...no C compiler could legitimately complain about that line.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I feel that compiling C code with a C++ compiler is a valid use case. My answer was an attempt to show that you could write a wrapper that would allow some C code that would normally be rejected to be accepted by the C++ compiler. I think the question can be left tagged with both C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you should use the new style casts:

```
    proc = static_cast<process *>(malloc(sizeof(struct process)));
```

But, if you really are using a C++ compiler, you should really be using `new`/`new[]` for dynamic allocation (and `delete`/`delete[]` for deallocation).

```
    proc = new process;
```

If you are porting C code to C++, and you don't want to modify the current `malloc()` calls, you can try adding this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace cxx {
    class voidptr {
        void *p_;
    public:
        voidptr (void *p = 0) : p_(p) {}
        template <typename T>
        operator T * () const { return static_cast<T *>(p_); }
    };
    voidptr malloc (size_t sz) { return ::malloc(sz); }
    voidptr calloc (size_t cnt, size_t sz) { return ::calloc(cnt, sz); }
    voidptr realloc (void *p, size_t newsz) { return ::realloc(p, newsz); }
}
#define malloc(x) cxx::malloc(x)
#define calloc(x,y) cxx::calloc(x,y)
#define realloc(x,y) cxx::realloc(x,y)
#endif
```

[Works for C.](http://ideone.com/1IQ6er) [Works for C++.](http://ideone.com/bS6CWU)

Comment: How about `using cxx::malloc;` instead of macros

Comment: The problem is ambiguity with the standard C functions.